# How to show title h1 on the top of the text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Need to add the code below to responsive website, but when I try to add H1 title, it is displayed under the image, and not on the top of the text. How to fix this?

```css
.bloque {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
}
ul li img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li p h1 {
    display: block;
}

@media ( min-width: 929px ) {
    ul li {
        display: table;
    }
    ul li img,
    ul li p {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bloque">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <img src="http://assets2.iavvo.com/assets/badges/badge_top_rating-9c22fb6971659ec79e63302e601816c5.png">
            <h1>TITLE HERE</h1>
            <p>Well, I'm sure I'm in serious need of some moral spankitude, but guess who's not qualified to be my Rabbi? Magic's all balderdash and chicanery.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this selector `ul li p h1` is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You have just to move h1 before img on your HTML... like this:

```
<div class="bloque">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <h1>TITLE HERE</h1>
            <img src="http://assets2.iavvo.com/assets/badges/badge_top_rating-9c22fb6971659ec79e63302e601816c5.png">
            <p>Well, I'm sure I'm in serious need of some moral spankitude, but guess who's not qualified to be my Rabbi? Magic's all balderdash and chicanery.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is when the title is long

Answer (score 0):

```
h1{width:100%;margin-left:280%;}
```

Why are you using table for Css layout?

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/OyroZP

Answer (score 0):

Change  `ul li p {
        display: table-cell;`

to `ul li p {
        display: block;`

and then if you want to center it all, just add `text-align:center` to your `.bloque` class.

Also
`ul li p h1` is not a correct selector. Your H1 is not inside of your paragraph so the selector is doing nothing.